How to download CSV file to update datatable/ag-grid table in plotly dash?
I have a small app displaying an AG-Grid table from an existing dataframe (the dataframe is originally a csv file read at the at the beginning of the app):
live_data = pd.read_csv('live_data.csv', index_col = 0)

app = Dash(__name__)

eurex_app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs([
        
        dcc.Tab(label='Live', style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style, children=[
             html.Br(),
             dag.AgGrid(
                 id="live_table",
                 className="ag-theme-balham",
                 defaultColDef={"filter": True, "autoHeaderHeight": True, "floatingFilter": True},
                 columnSize="sizeToFit",
                 style={"height": 800, "width": '100%'},
                 rowData=eurex_live_datatable.to_dict("records"),
                 columnDefs=live_columns,
                 getRowStyle = getRowStyle,
                 dashGridOptions={"pagination": True, 'tooltipMouseTrack': True}),
            dbc.Button("Refresh", id = 'refresh_button', n_clicks=0, style={'width' :'10%', 'fontWeight': 'bold', "margin-left": "850px", 'backgroundColor': '#F9F6EE', 'font-family':'Calibri', 'margin-top': '12px', 'border-color':'blue'})
        ]),
   ])
])


I added a button trying to use it to update the ag-grid table by reading the new csv:
@app.callback(Output('live_table', 'data'),
                    Input('refresh_button', 'n_clicks'),
                    prevent_initial_call = True)

def update_live(n_clicks): 

    if not n_clicks: 
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    df = pd.read_csv('live_data.csv', index_col = 0)
    live_data = format_live(df)
    
    return live_data.to_dict("records")


It seems I am missing something...is there anything related to external downloads from the app...
I saw some explanations about some  @app.server connection to allow downloading CSV file in dash apps but can't get my head on it. If anyone had this use case by the past...
Thanks

Can you add the full code? Having issues with the Eurex_live_datatable and so on. For now I can say that you might need to check the dcc.Download component, that's the best way to download data from Dash

Yes indeed thanks, might be more acutally on dcc.Upload so when you click a button it loads the updated csv, perofrm calculations before display
